# How to call a function from html file to js type module file?

Tags: javascript

First of all, give thanks for reading my question and try to help me and apologize for my English.

I have the following problem ...

I would like from the html to execute a function of a js file that I have created, to which you pass two parameters: the name of the map and the id where the map should be loaded. But being a module type tells me it is not defined. However, if that file js is not a module type and does not have any import if it recognizes and executes it.

My code is the following ...

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Map Generator</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script type="module" src='./js/index.js'></script>
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.46.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.46.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        customMap.addMap("icgc", "map");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js file

```
import MapFunctions from './class/MapFunctions.js'

// new MapFunctions().createMap("openstreetmaps", "map");

var customMap = {
    addMap: function name(base, target) {
        new MapFunctions().createMap(base, target);
    }
}
```

With the constructor it works, but the purpose is that from the index.html you only have to make the call to the function customMap.addMap () and only importing the file index.js

[Here](https://github.com/jadelmag/MapFunctions) you have the repository in case you see it there more clearly

Thank you